# Converter and validators messages in dutch

Tags: xpages, converters, validation

I have a question about converters. On one of my fields I added an converter to change the field value into an date. Whenever a user enters the incorrect date/time format an error is shown " This field is not a valid date. ".

I want to force it to be in dutch. Could i Change the local to simply show it in dutch or should i write custom converter ( don't hope so ) with a dutch message returned?

Related to this , I Think, are the messages for validators. I have an expression validator which returns "Expression is invalid"  message when the computed expression ( it is saved in a notes document and read on page load ) is invalid. Can I somehow change this to dutch? So that the user knows what is going on?

Comment: Changing the locale changes messages in for instance name picker dialogs.

But, I just tested in one of my apps (with proper locale changes) and here I see the same non-translated message if I enter an invalid date (on Domino 8.5.3 and Upgrade Pack 1).

Comment: I have already tried to override the existing converter and change it with my own, but was not able to get it to work correctly.

Comment: Same here, just yesterday I was wanting to override the message with something more user friendly and it is ignored.  Mine was in a dojo currency text box.  Sounds like a bug on a global level, and not with the specific control.

Comment: Do you have a sample?

Comment: I too would be very interested in a solution to this problem